# The getter 'title' was called on null

Tags: flutter, null, dependencies, media-queries, getter

i am  making an shopping app UI through FLUTTER, during development it is showing some error, when i use (product.tittle ,product.image,product.price) . the error says The getter 'title' was called on null , same for price and image .
here is my code-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:shopping/constants.dart';
import 'package:shopping/models/Product.dart';


class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;
  const Body({Key key, this.product}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // it provides us total height and width
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(

        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: size.height,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.height * 0.3),
                  height: 500,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(24),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPaddin),
                  child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text("Aristocratic Hand Bag",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                     Text(
                       product.title,
                     style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.copyWith(
                       color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                     ),),
                     Row(
                       children: [
                         RichText(text: TextSpan(
                           children: [
                             TextSpan(text: "Price\n"),
                             TextSpan(
                               text: "${product.price}",
                               style: Theme.of(context)
                                 .textTheme
                                 .headline4
                                 .copyWith(
                                 color: Colors.white,
                                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                               )
                             ),

                           ]
                         ),),
                         SizedBox(width: kDefaultPaddin),
                         Expanded(child: Image.asset(product.image))
                       ],
                     )

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}'''
```

product.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Product {
  final String image, title, description;
  final int price, size, id;
  final Color color;
  Product({
    this.id,
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.price,
    this.description,
    this.size,
    this.color,
  });
}

List<Product> products = [
  Product(
      id: 1,
      title: "Office Code",
      price: 234,
      size: 12,
      description: dummyText,
      image: "assets/images/bag_1.png",
      color: Color(0xFF3D82AE)),
  Product(
      id: 2,
      title: "Belt Bag",
      price: 234,
      size: 8,
      description: dummyText,
      image: "assets/images/bag_2.png",
      color: Color(0xFFD3A984)),
  Product(
      id: 3,
      title: "Hang Top",
      price: 234,
      size: 10,
      description: dummyText,
      image: "assets/images/bag_3.png",
      color: Color(0xFF989493)),
  Product(
      id: 4,
      title: "Old Fashion",
      price: 234,
      size: 11,
      description: dummyText,
      image: "assets/images/bag_4.png",
      color: Color(0xFFE6B398)),
  Product(
      id: 5,
      title: "Office Code",
      price: 234,
      size: 12,
      description: dummyText,
      image: "assets/images/bag_5.png",
      color: Color(0xFFFB7883)),
  Product(
    id: 6,
    title: "Office Code",
    price: 234,
    size: 12,
    description: dummyText,
    image: "assets/images/bag_6.png",
    color: Color(0xFFAEAEAE),
  ),
];

String dummyText =
    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since. When an unknown printer took a galley.";
```

error -

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86 64...
Restarted application in 1,256ms.

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Body(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery]):
The getter 'title' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: title

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Body file:///home/nitin/AndroidStudioProjects/shopping/lib/Screens/home/details/details_screen.dart:33:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      Body.build (package:shopping/Screens/home/details/body.dart:41:32)
#2      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4638:28)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4564:15)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4280:5)
...
```

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

1.body.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:shopping/Screens/home/components/categories.dart';
import 'package:shopping/Screens/home/components/item_card.dart';
import 'package:shopping/Screens/home/details/details_screen.dart';
import 'package:shopping/constants.dart';
import 'package:shopping/models/Product.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPaddin),
          child: Text(
              "Women",
            style: Theme.of(context)
            .textTheme
            .headline5
            .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        Categories(),
        Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPaddin),
              child: GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                    mainAxisSpacing: kDefaultPaddin,
                    crossAxisSpacing: kDefaultPaddin,
                    childAspectRatio: 0.75,
                  ),
                  itemCount: products.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, [index]) => ItemCard(
                      product: products[index],
                      press: () => Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(
                                product: products[index],
                              )
                          )),
                  ),
              ),
            ),
        )

      ],
    );
  }
}
```

2.categories.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shopping/constants.dart';

class Categories extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategoriesState createState() => _CategoriesState();
}

class _CategoriesState extends State<Categories> {
  List<String> categories = ["Hand Bags","Jewellery","Footwear","Dresses"];
  int selectedIndex = 0 ;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: kDefaultPaddin),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 25.0,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: categories.length,
          itemBuilder: (context , index) => GestureDetector( onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              selectedIndex = index ;
            });
          },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPaddin),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    categories[index],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: selectedIndex == index ? kTextColor : kTextLightColor ,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: kDefaultPaddin/4),
                    height: 2,
                    width: 30,
                    color: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.black : Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

3 item_card.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shopping/constants.dart';
import 'package:shopping/models/Product.dart';

class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;
  final Function press;
  const ItemCard ({
    Key key,
    this.product,
    this.press,
  }) : super(key : key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: press,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPaddin),

              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: product.color,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0)
              ),
              child: Image.asset(product.image),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: kDefaultPaddin/4),
            child: Text(
              product.title,
              style: TextStyle(color: kTextLightColor),
            ),
          ),
          Text("₹${product.price}",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

4.detais screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:shopping/Screens/home/details/body.dart';
import 'package:shopping/constants.dart';
import 'package:shopping/models/Product.dart';


class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;

  const DetailsScreen({Key key, this.product}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: product.color,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: product.color,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: IconButton(icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/back.svg",
        color: Colors.white,),
            onPressed:() => Navigator.pop(context) ),
        actions: [IconButton(
          icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/search.svg"),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
          IconButton(
            icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/cart.svg"),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        SizedBox(width: kDefaultPaddin/2),
        ],
      ),
      body: Body(),
    );
  }
}
```

5 home_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:shopping/Screens/home/components/body.dart';
import 'package:shopping/constants.dart';



class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/back.svg"),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/search.svg",color: kTextColor,),
              onPressed: null
          ),
        SizedBox(width: kDefaultPaddin/ 2 )
        ],
      ),
      body: Body(),

    );
  }
}
```

6 constant.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const kTextColor = Color(0xFF535353);
const kTextLightColor = Color(0xFFACACAC);

const kDefaultPaddin = 20.0;
```

7 main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shopping/Screens/home/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:shopping/constants.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(bodyColor: kTextColor),
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you never initialized the value of your product variable.
Set a value of your product and it will work just fine.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it ,step by step

Comment: your have all your products in `products` list.. So when you are creating `Body` widget, you need to pass a product as a parameter.. Like `Body(product: products[0])`

Comment: text widget is not taking it

Comment: text widget is not taking it , i tried Text(product : products[0] )

Comment: not Text widget. It's the Body widget you have shared in your code

Comment: inside the Body class ,there is a Text widget where i am using product.tittle

Comment: I know that.. its because your product object itself is null. You need to provide a product object while creating the Body widget

Comment: nitin05sept@gmail.com this is my gmail , please tell me what should i do, in detail there

Comment: please help me.

Comment: you have created `Body()` widget in your details_screen.drat and home_screen.dart. Just add your product there. Instead of `Body()`, write `Body(product: products[0])`

Comment: Could you please upvote and mark this as right answer? @Nitin

Answer (score 0):

with the title, you can protect the app from crashing by using

```
Text(product.title.toString())
//or
Text(product.title?? 'Default title')
```

both would work but it depends on your goal though.

and for the image you can check first if the image is null or not, and based on that you display the image.

```
 Expanded(child: Image.asset(product.image??'images/your_default_image.jpg'))
```

Comment: thats because your product has no values, try to set them

Comment: product.dart file

Comment: this file contains the values

Comment: I can't tell but you probably missed something.